# Mongo GetBytes Issue, IE8, Facebook, PHP

Tags: php, facebook, mongodb, internet-explorer-8

```
if ($file = $gridfs->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($fid)))) {  

    return $file->getBytes();
}
```

This file is returning just fine when it's on its own in IE8 (and every decent browser, of course). However, when I'm in a Facebook app frame, it dies. White page (within FB). I've checked for PHP errors as well as Mongo (lastError). If I run it before the getBytes() (that is, if the error was in FindOne), I get the no errors array. If I run it after I get nothing. In fact, the only way to get anything is to exit() right before the getBytes call. The behavior is similar to a memory overload, but I'm not getting an error in PHP. I have never seen this before, I am at a complete loss. I have not seen anyone with an issue that was both browser and iFrame specific involving GridFS. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do see for traffic using Fiddler?

Comment: EEk - using a PC in virtualization, have never played with Fiddler... I'll look....